# Use macros with doseq to generate spec

Tags: clojure, macros, clojure.spec

I find myself writing a lot of specs like this:

```
(s/def ::name string?)
(s/def ::logUri string?)
(s/def ::subnet (s/and string? #(> (count %) 5)))
(s/def ::instanceType string?)
...
(s/def ::key (s/and string? #(> (count %) 5)))
(s/def ::instanceCount string?)
(s/def ::bidPct string?)
```

I.e. Lots of `s/and` and `s/def`. This seems like a waste. So I decided to write a macro that did this for me. Something like:

```
(defmacro and-spec [validations]
  (doseq [[keyname & funcs] validations]
    `(s/def ~keyname (s/and ~@funcs))))
```

So I would be able to do something like:

```
(and-spec [[::name1 [string?]]
           [::name2  [string? #(> (count %) 5)]]])
```

And this would just do all my `s/def` stuff for me. Unfortunately, the above macro doesn't work, but I'm not sure why.

```
(s/valid? ::name1 "asdf")
Execution error at emr-cli.utils/eval6038 (form-init17784784591561795514.clj:1).
Unable to resolve spec: :emr-cli.utils/name1
```

Smaller versions of this work:

```
(defmacro small-and-spec-works [key-name validations]
  `(s/def ~key-name (s/and ~@validations)))
=> #'emr-cli.utils/tsmall
(and-spec-small-works ::mykey [string?])
=> :emr-cli.utils/mykey
(s/valid? ::mykey "asdf")
=> true
```

But the second I introduce a let binding things start getting weird:

```
(defmacro small-and-spec [validation]
  (let [[key-name & valids] validation]
    `(s/def ~key-name (s/and ~@valids))))
=> #'emr-cli.utils/small-and-spec
(small-and-spec [::mykey2 [string?]])
=> :emr-cli.utils/mykey2
(s/valid? ::mykey2 "asdf")
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at emr-cli.utils/eval6012 (form-init17784784591561795514.clj:1).
Key must be integer
```

1. How can I make the `doseq` macro work?
2. What is going wrong with the `small-and-spec` that creates the `Key must be integer` error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defmacro and-spec [defs]
    `(do
        ~@(map (fn [[name rest]]
              `(s/def ~name (s/and ~@rest))) defs)))
```

`doseq` is for side effects. It always returns `nil`.

Comment: Yes, the "side effect" in question is the definition of multiple in-scope specs. I don't want the macro to return a list of defs.

Comment: "I don't want the macro to return a list of defs."  is actually what you want though, in a do

Comment: Specifically because just creating a source code list does not cause it to be evaluated. The "contract" of a macro is that any code it returns will be evaluated. Code it produces as a side effect and then throws away is, naturally, thrown away.